# Resource handling in mediacodec

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, android-mediacodec, smart-tv

Update :
I solved this issue by forcibly killing a application which doesn't release mediacodec When goes to background state . In this way first i internally forcibly released the mediacodec and Then kill the application .
..........................................................................

I have 2 different mediaplayer application , Which runs on android L on a smart TV .

Both the application Uses MediaCodec for playback . But the Issue is When One application is running If you launch the other application it doesn't play video , Because the previous application didn't call mediacodec.release() (and because of this there is a resource problem in OMX level )

So My question is , How to handle resouce in Mediacodec native  Level ?

Currently i have this mechanism :

1) I have a Resource manager . Which can allocate Resource to one client and Preempt Resources from other client .

2) Lets Say 2 apps are  app1 and app2 .

3) lets say , user opened app1 So it tries to create mediacodec , in which i try to acquire Resource and Since no Body is currently holding The Resources  it gets them ..and then it create mediacodec components ..etc..

4) Now user launched app2 to play some file , so app1 just got audioFocus lost , and then app2 tries to create mediacodec , in which i again tries to acquire Resources . But this time Since app1 is currently holding The Resoucres , Resmanager ask cleint of app1 to release the Resoucres .

And here the problem happens , Because resouce will be released When app will call mediacodec,release() , and i dont have any control over How to say to a application to release mediacodec .

There is no standard way in android L , to send ERROR from mediacodec native level to ask application to release mediacodec ..

Does any one has idea , How to handle such situations , i.e How to ask a application to release Mediacodec ???

Comment: Release the MediaCodec instances when the activity is paused.

Comment: Thanks @fadden  But problem is there are many application who never releases the mediacodec until they are killed by system .

So , i was actually asking for a mechanism in Which we can actually Release() the mediacodec internally without informing the app incase 
there is a resource problem with another app Which currently tries to acquire mediacodec.